# django edit multiple id at once with selecting checkbox

Tags: django, edit

I have items where I can easily edit one by one all working nice but in case I want to edit multiple id's at once via selecting with checkbox I am stuck and can't get it work. Where am I doing wrong ?

Here is my codes:

fast_edit.html  -> I am passing variables via instance to field.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {%for field in instance %}
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="100">
                {{field.label_tag}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{field}}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update FP Item</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

forms.py

```
class FastFPForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FP
        fields = ['FP_Item', 'P_1', 'P_2']
        widgets = {
            'FP_Item': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 3}),
            'P_1': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 1}),
            'P_2': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 1}),

        }
```

view.py  --> I am sending variables to fast_edit function

```
def items_home(request):
        pfast_type = request.GET.get("pfast_type")
        item = request.GET.get("fastedit")
        ........
        elif pfast_type and item:
            return fast_edit(pfast_type,item)
```

Here is my function:

```
def fast_edit(request,id=None):
    if not request.user.is_active:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        instance=get_object_or_404(FP,id=item)
        form = FastFPForm(request.POST or None,instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user_id = request.user.id
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
        context={
        'FP' : FP.FP_Item,
        'instance': instance,
            'form': form
    }
        return render(request, 'fast_edit.html', context)
```

This is my inputs for fastedit and pfast_type to get the id's and the type.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="P_1" name="pfast_type" value="P_1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ obj.id }}" name="fastedit" value="{{ obj.id }}"/>
```

I know that my function is not correct but I couldn't fix it according to my need, so what I want to do is if P_1 checked, I want all selected items editable for P_1 field, if I select P_2 again all selected items editable for me to be able to save on fast_edit page.

Is my logic false ?  Is there any other easier method for editing multiple id at once via selecting with checkbox or if I am on the right track can you please give me hint to solve this. Thank you

I added but I don't think I need url right as like as we are editing single id like  url(r'^detail/(?P\d+)/$',

urls.py

```
url(r'^fast_edit/$', views.fast_edit, name='fast_edit'),
```

Comment: Any comment ? Isn't this possible with django to update multiple id's at once from single page ?